# CLR Stored Procedure with C# throwing errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

Hi I am working on making a CLR stored procedure using C#, for which I am learning through examples.

Below is what I am trying now

```
public static void GetProductsByPrice(int price)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true");
    connection.Open();

    string commandText = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE PRICE < " + price.ToString();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // Create the record and specify the metadata for the columns.
    SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(
        new SqlMetaData("col1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100),
        new SqlMetaData("col2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100));

    // Mark the begining of the result-set.
    SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

    // Send 10 rows back to the client. 
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Set values for each column in the row.
        record.SetString(0, reader[1].ToString()); //productName
        record.SetString(1, reader[2].ToString()); // productDescription
        // Send the row back to the client.
        SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
    }

    // Mark the end of the result-set.
    SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd();
}
```

But when I try to run it I get the below errors

> *Msg 6549, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetProductsByPrice, Line 0
>
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'GetProductsByPrice':
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The locale identifier (LCID) 16393 is not supported by SQL Server.
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SmiEventSink_Default.DispatchMessages(Boolean ignoreNonFatalMessages)
>
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlPipe.SendResultsStart(SqlDataRecord record)
>
>   at StoredProcedures.GetProductsByPrice(Int32 price)
>
>   User transaction, if any, will be rolled back.*

I am referring to this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlpipe.sendresultsstart.aspx) for the code.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Try it with: `new SqlMetaData("col1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, 1033, SqlCompareOptions.None), new SqlMetaData("col2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, 1033, SqlCompareOptions.None)`

Comment: Side note: please use parameters, rather than constructing SQL as a string. It's a good habit to get into to always do so.

Comment: @nemesv you are awesome ! it worked ! please post your comment as answer, I will happily accept it :) Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception states: `The locale identifier (LCID) 16393 is not supported by SQL`

The [SqlMetaData.LocaleId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata.localeid.aspx) property contains the locale ID of the column or parameter where **the default value is the current locale of the current thread.**

The default value in this your case `16393` which is the `English - India` locale ([see table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx)) but it seems your SQL server was installed with a different locale `English - United States`

So you have three options:

1. Configure/ReInstall your SQL server to use the locale `English - India`
2. Change the locale of your current thread to a local which is supported by SQL server
3. Specify the locale manually when creating the `SqlMetaData`:

   ```
    SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(
     new SqlMetaData("col1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1033, SqlCompareOptions.None),
     new SqlMetaData("col2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1033, SqlCompareOptions.None));
   ```

   Where the 1033 is the Locale ID of `English - United States`