# Locale ID SQL Server issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I am having a problem replicating a SQL server database. I am using a transactional replication and just finished creating my local publication when i receive this error while the snapshot agent was running:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "sp_scriptdropinsreconciliationproc_sqlclr":
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The locale identifier (LCID) 1072
>   is not supported by SQL

Can someone please help me with this situation? thanks & much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CLR Stored Procedure with C# throwing errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438456/clr-stored-procedure-with-c-sharp-throwing-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solving this issue was simple.i had the wrong windows locale language pack selected when SQL server was installed the first time .Steps i took:

1. uninstall SQL server.
2. changed locale ID to its appropriate selection (South African to USA Locale as SQL Server did not recognize my locale ID "soto" (South Africa). ).
3. re-installed SQL Server on the new locale ID.
4. Replication works.
5. Great Success.

So Tanner was right but i wanted to provide a clearer answer to those who might experience this problem in future.